# Countdown component: how to prevent re-rendering in Angular2?

Tags: angular, angularjs

I have an Angular2 master component which includes a number of child components and an independant countdown component (named "clock" in the code below). Countdown component changes it's label every second and that causes the master component and all others to (needlessly) re-render. How can I prevent that?
This is the source of my countdown component:

```
import {Component, Input} from 'angular2/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'clock',
    template: `
        <span>
            {{caption}}
        </span>
    `
})
export class ClockComponent {
    public caption;
    @Input('seconds') seconds :number = 0;
    constructor() {
      var self = this;
      setInterval(function(){
            self.seconds--;
            self.caption = self.getCaption(self.seconds);
      }, 1000);
      this.caption = this.getCaption(this.seconds);
    }

    getCaption (seconds): string {
        let h = Math.floor(seconds / (60*60));
        let m = Math.floor((seconds - 60 * 60 * h) / 60);
        let s = seconds % 60;
        return ((h < 10) ? '0' : '') + h + ':'
             + ((m < 10) ? '0' : '') + m + ':'
             + ((s < 10) ? '0' : '') + s ;
    }
}
```

and you can imagine it being embedded alongside others in "my-app"; something like:

```
<clock [seconds]="1800"></clock>
<other-comps>...</other-comps>...
```

EDIT (per comment): 
When I mean re-render, this is what happens:
I've added a console.log printout to other components (nav and question, see image below) on various rendering actions, for instance, a component has a class binder, eg:
    [class.selected]="isSelected"
and I've added console.log() to the isSelected() method and can thus spot that it is called every one second, every time the countdown (clock) refreshes itself. I'd like for the countdown to change label (count down from eg 30 minutes) WITHOUT affecting nav and question components and causing them to re-render.

[image: master and child components]

EDIT (2):

And here is the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/PwBfUQXyZyTrqPaqrwRm?p=preview

Fire up the console and watch for six those "q-nav isSelected?" appearing every second (printed from qnav component).

Comment: Can you please add more information? I don't see anything about `Countdown` component in your code. How are they related. What do you mean by "re-rerender"?

Comment: Angular allows [*one-time binding* expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#one-time-binding), which means adding a prefix of `::` to binding expressions causes Angular to only evaluate them once (when the page is loaded), and not to re-evaluate them when the DOM changes.

Comment: David, the :: expression of Angular 1 is not there in Angular 2.
Also, I want the opposite - I want a component to be 'isolated' from other components, so as not to influence them. Other child components SHOULD impact each other. Is there a way to inject HTML into the master app component, but make Angular ignore it (though it changes it's appearance).

Comment: What do you mean by "re-render"? Can you demonstrate in a Plunker?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer - just did, see the "edit (2)".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's Angular's change detection that is invoked on every event, and `setInterval` calling the callback is such an event.

You can switch change detection to `OnPush` so change detection only takes place when an `@Input()` is updated or when you invoke change detection explicitly, for example by calling methods on `ChangeDetectorRefs`

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit, EventEmitter, Output, OnChanges, ChangeDetectionStrategy} from 'angular2/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'q-nav',
    template: `
        <span *ngFor="#a of currAnswers; #i = index" class="aii-qn"
            [class.selected]="isSelected(i)"
            (click)="onSelect(i)">
            <span class="badge">{{ i+1 }}</span>
        </span>
    `,
    styles: [`
        .aii-qn {
            color: #0000ff;
            cursor: pointer;
            font-size: 2rem;
        }
        .selected {
            border: black solid 2px;
        }

    `],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
```

For more details see:
http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html

Comment: Just to be sure: I was hoping I could somehow tell (in once place) that clock component should not bother other components (something like 'DontPropagateChange') , but the only way is, as you put it, to set changeDetection to EVERY other component?

Comment: AFAIK `OnPush` should be the preferred detection strategy anyway and `CheckAlways` (default) only be used when appropriate. I think `CheckAlways` is only the default for an easier start when learning Angular2.